# Heroku - We're sorry, but something went wrong - Issue occurring only on Heroku not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Sorry to bother but I really don't know what else to try. I have pushed my rails application to heroku and during the last push everything went well except that one of the pages (projects#index) returns this error in Heroku:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

The same doesn't occur in Cloud 9 when I run the server locally. The same page shows without issues.

Looking at previous answers, I've tried running:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I also tried re-pushing everything by running the following commands:

```
git push heroku
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rails db:migrate
heroku run rails db:seed
heroku restart
```

Here are my heroku logs:

```
2016-11-09T18:48:22.095610+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2016-11-09T18:48:22.095627+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2016-11-09T18:48:22.096004+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-11-09T18:48:22.095780+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3666
2016-11-09T18:48:22.259703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T18:48:24.502298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=2c6f6731-bedc-4367-83f9-f40a87273fe5 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1402ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T18:48:24.790630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=4dae94ac-b865-4514-b59b-074591a69d05 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T18:49:18.903562+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate` by alessia.bass@yahoo.ie
2016-11-09T18:49:23.120484+00:00 heroku[run.7366]: Awaiting client
2016-11-09T18:49:23.143476+00:00 heroku[run.7366]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2016-11-09T18:49:23.302666+00:00 heroku[run.7366]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T18:49:28.044047+00:00 heroku[run.7366]: State changed from up to complete
2016-11-09T18:49:28.029405+00:00 heroku[run.7366]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-09T18:49:39.596513+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:seed` by alessia.bass@yahoo.ie
2016-11-09T18:49:44.198548+00:00 heroku[run.3484]: Awaiting client
2016-11-09T18:49:44.246315+00:00 heroku[run.3484]: Starting process with command `rails db:seed`
2016-11-09T18:49:44.304728+00:00 heroku[run.3484]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T18:49:50.403853+00:00 heroku[run.3484]: State changed from up to complete
2016-11-09T18:49:50.393367+00:00 heroku[run.3484]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-09T18:50:11.659495+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=73beb6fe-90c6-41c9-8f75-e8939fd7a4be fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=109ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T18:50:11.861324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=694b31e7-b3df-4c00-85fa-d931d6f3ba11 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T18:50:13.257178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=0c7878ec-0017-48a2-a53d-55126ca12a97 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T18:50:13.422750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=8c44d51f-ca89-487b-ae25-eb06ef04735e fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T18:50:25.482365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-11-09T18:50:25.483959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-11-09T18:50:28.492311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-11-09T18:50:29.151373+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2016-11-09T18:50:29.151850+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2016-11-09 18:50:29 +0000 ===
2016-11-09T18:50:29.151889+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2016-11-09T18:50:29.152378+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-11-09T18:50:29.358836+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-09T18:50:29.841404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 22013 -e production`
2016-11-09T18:50:35.820996+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2016-11-09T18:50:35.821017+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:22013
2016-11-09T18:50:35.821018+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-11-09T18:50:37.033565+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2016-11-09T18:50:37.033582+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
2016-11-09T18:50:37.033585+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2016-11-09T18:50:37.033617+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2016-11-09T18:50:37.033865+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:22013
2016-11-09T18:50:37.034023+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-11-09T18:50:37.177370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T18:50:37.930818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=01420f22-76e1-4916-be34-e96e5db985df fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=424ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T18:50:38.121454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=89d07228-0172-4809-8a43-241662cdfdcb fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T18:52:12.082290+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by alessia.bass@yahoo.ie
2016-11-09T18:52:18.172017+00:00 heroku[run.6086]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T18:52:18.336471+00:00 heroku[run.6086]: Awaiting client
2016-11-09T18:52:18.372809+00:00 heroku[run.6086]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-11-09T18:52:23.522954+00:00 heroku[run.6086]: State changed from up to complete
2016-11-09T18:52:23.513862+00:00 heroku[run.6086]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-09T18:52:30.397822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=8a1dc1d5-1f5b-425b-8deb-c0d60dbe15bb fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=61ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T18:52:30.602701+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=6105f2be-9c60-4d35-8ff2-cc4fcf7b438f fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T18:52:32.824633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=074d3fc0-9ad1-4c50-9325-139d392b502b fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=40ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T18:52:32.985752+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=f13fa5bf-5f2f-48f7-92eb-ff09beb5919d fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T18:52:37.881288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=e3d2067c-b093-41e0-9d6f-72a68f172edf fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=50ms status=200 bytes=3208
2016-11-09T18:52:42.036223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=df869638-2c3a-40ac-b0a7-ba4a3190cdd6 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T18:53:01.489311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=dd949ce7-bfb1-422b-81fd-8ebc02540e71 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=71ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T19:13:01.823684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=62e72010-b749-4a8e-9f5d-3ee2550e4eb5 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T19:24:19.274988+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by alessia.bass@yahoo.ie
2016-11-09T19:24:25.388503+00:00 heroku[run.8672]: Awaiting client
2016-11-09T19:24:25.463637+00:00 heroku[run.8672]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-11-09T19:24:25.535795+00:00 heroku[run.8672]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T19:24:33.095488+00:00 heroku[run.8672]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-09T19:24:33.081820+00:00 heroku[run.8672]: State changed from up to complete
2016-11-09T19:25:12.201241+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=529aeacd-e9b9-4b96-a2d7-34ddb5d3896e fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T19:25:12.469696+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=99e6fa84-47c2-4ae4-86cc-9f4e9f36ca16 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48
2016-11-09T19:28:30.885743+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails consoe` by alessia.bass@yahoo.ie
2016-11-09T19:28:35.368273+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: Awaiting client
2016-11-09T19:28:35.393535+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: Starting process with command `rails consoe`
2016-11-09T19:28:35.539374+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T19:28:38.853885+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: State changed from up to complete
2016-11-09T19:28:38.878693+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: Process exited with status 1
2016-11-09T19:28:46.270972+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by alessia.bass@yahoo.ie
2016-11-09T19:28:51.734321+00:00 heroku[run.9640]: Awaiting client
2016-11-09T19:28:51.769438+00:00 heroku[run.9640]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2016-11-09T19:28:51.802682+00:00 heroku[run.9640]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T19:29:03.378053+00:00 heroku[run.9640]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-09T19:29:03.393812+00:00 heroku[run.9640]: State changed from up to complete
2016-11-09T19:29:16.843286+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-11-09T19:29:16.843982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-11-09T19:29:20.220947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-11-09T19:29:21.247977+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2016-11-09T19:29:21.248148+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2016-11-09 19:29:21 +0000 ===
2016-11-09T19:29:21.248152+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2016-11-09T19:29:21.248232+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-11-09T19:29:21.388099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-09T19:29:21.832713+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21042 -e production`
2016-11-09T19:29:25.892825+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2016-11-09T19:29:25.892864+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:21042
2016-11-09T19:29:25.892865+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-11-09T19:29:26.922809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-11-09T19:29:26.844730+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2016-11-09T19:29:26.844748+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
2016-11-09T19:29:26.844749+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2016-11-09T19:29:26.844750+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2016-11-09T19:29:26.844827+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:21042
2016-11-09T19:29:26.845007+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-11-09T19:29:28.618363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/projects" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=ae553309-c165-4526-b443-fd098df71c47 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=139ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-11-09T19:29:28.754190+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=453d6e7f-b4e8-4337-9340-84cb8dcaa95f fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T19:29:28.910252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=79a6c43e-1ef3-4467-a60e-2c83d7ae0e83 fwd="86.44.57.230" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143
2016-11-09T19:29:30.017146+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-falls-63733.herokuapp.com request_id=0dcba4a6-2113-437c-acb3-4383f16dd191 fwd="104.131.194.174" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143
```

This is my index view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All Projects') %>

<h1>All Projects</h1>
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
            data-toggle="dropdown">Filter by Team<span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% Team.all.each do |team| %>
            <li>
              <%= link_to team.tName, projects_path(team: team.tName), class: "link" %>
            </li>
            <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:team] == team.tName %>">
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to "Remove Team Filters", projects_path, class: "link" %></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>





<ul class="users">
  <%= render 'projects/projectindex' %>
</ul>
```

And the partial rendered is:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
<h2><%= params[:team] %></h2>
      <% if @projects.count == 0 %>
            <h2>There are no projects currently in this category</h2>
      <% end %>
      <li>
            Title: <%= project.title %><br>

            Team: <%= project.team.tName%><br>

            Description: <%= project.description %><br>

            Status:<%= project.status %><br>

            Type: <%= project.p_type %><br>

            Updated: <%= time_ago_in_words(project.updated_at) %> ago.
      </li>
<% end %>
```

Any idea how I can fix the issue?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Other pages works normally, or this problem happens only in `projects#index`?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that! Yes everything else works perfectly. The issue only occurs in projects#index and only in heroku.

Comment: You aren't seeing any error logs indicating the problem? Maybe the problem is in `project.team.tName`. If a project doesn't have any team, `project.team` will return _nil_ and so `nil.tName` will raise an `undefined method 'tName for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: @Lucas Costa - Thank you very much for your reply. I have downloaded the database to check this and all projects have a team assigned to them.  If this was a problem wouldn't it throw an error when I run the pages locally? This is not a rhetorical question, I really wouldn't know. When I run the pages locally I see all projects assigned to team id 1 as expected.

Comment: Yes. You're absolutely right. Initially I would say that problem could be related to assets compilation. But you said that other pages are working normally... A log with error messages would be great to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Lucas Costa - How can I get that? I ran `heroku logs --tail`and pasted it in my question. When I check the Chrome developer tools > Console I see  _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)_ - In Firefox it shows JS document as "cause"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... as everything was working locally I continued with my work by adding a new model, similar to the project one that I had already created. I pushed everything to heroku and following the same steps as before:

```
git push heroku
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rails db:migrate
heroku run rails db:seed
heroku restart
```

When I went into the heroku site, the error on the project index page was no longer occurring. I didn't touch anything on any of the project pages as the new model is independent from the project one... I really don't know why!

Thanks to @Lucas Costa for trying to help and for anybody that has taken the time to read my question.